# Trouble with authenticating Google Analytics API batch request in python app

Tags: python, google-analytics

Having trouble authenticating batch request for Google Analytics API.

I have a credential .json file which looks like this.

```
    {
        "type": "service_account",
        "project_id": "xxx",
        "private_key_id": "xxx",
        "private_key": "xxx",
        "client_email": "xxx",
        "client_id": "xxx",
        "client_secret":"xxx",
        "auth_uri": "xxx",
        "token_uri": "xxx",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "xxx",
        "client_x509_cert_url": "xxx"
    }
```

This is my callback function

```
    def test_callback(request_id, response, exception):
        """Handle batched request responses."""
        print request_id
        if exception is not None:
            if isinstance(exception, HttpError):
                message = json.loads(exception.content)['error']['message']
                print ('Request %s returned API error : %s : %s ' %
                     (request_id, exception.resp.status, message))
            else:
                print response
```

This is where I authenticate

```
    """Init and return the Google Analytics service"""
        CREDS = 'credentials/google.json'
        scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(CREDS, scopes)
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credentials.authorize(http)
```

This is where I try to add the batch request

```
    """
    This is the function I use in a helper file.  No execute on the end
    def ga_service_test(service, profile_id, start_date, end_date):
        # ensure lower case
        ids = "ga:" + profile_id
        metrics = "ga:pageviewsPerSession"
        return service.data().ga().get(
            ids=ids, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, metrics=metrics
            )"""

    # Build the Analytics Service Object with the authorized http object
        session = build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)

        batch = BatchHttpRequest(callback=test_callback)

        a_session = ga_service_test(session, a_id, yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        b_session = ga_service_test(session, b_id, yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        c_session = ga_service_test(session, c_id, yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

        for request in [a_session, b_session, c_session]:
            batch.add(request)

        return batch.execute(http=httplib2.Http())
```

I continue to get this error in my terminal

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store-two/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
    15:47:09 web.1  |     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store-two/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 176, in handle_request
    15:47:09 web.1  |     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store-two/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    15:47:09 web.1  |     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store-two/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    15:47:09 web.1  |     response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store-two/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    15:47:09 web.1  |     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store-two/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    15:47:09 web.1  |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store-two/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    15:47:09 web.1  |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store-two/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    15:47:09 web.1  |     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store-two/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    15:47:09 web.1  |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store-two/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    15:47:09 web.1  |     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store/application.py", line 84, in test
    15:47:09 web.1  |     return batch.execute(http=httplib2.Http())
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store-two/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 140, in positional_wrapper
    15:47:09 web.1  |     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store-two/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 1325, in execute
    15:47:09 web.1  |     self._execute(http, self._order, self._requests)
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store-two/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 1249, in _execute
    15:47:09 web.1  |     body = self._serialize_request(request)
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store-two/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 1120, in _serialize_request
    15:47:09 web.1  |     request.http.request.credentials.apply(headers)
    15:47:09 web.1  |   File "/Users/bjones/test-app-two/data-store-two/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 676, in apply
    15:47:09 web.1  |     headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + self.access_token
    15:47:09 web.1  | TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

```
This is my full .py file.  I am assuming it has something to do with my authentication process but I can't seem to figure it out.  If someone could help point me in the right direction it would help.
```

```
    import requests
    import json

    from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, abort, render_template
    import time
    import calendar

    from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
    import httplib2

    from apiclient.errors import HttpError
    from apiclient.discovery import build
    from apiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

    # Helper functions from another file
    from utils.helpers import ga_service, get_sessions, ga_service_test, get_pageviewsPerSession, hyphendate

    from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware

    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging locally
    app.debug = True

    def test_callback(request_id, response, exception):
        """Handle batched request responses."""
        print request_id
        if exception is not None:
            if isinstance(exception, HttpError):
                message = json.loads(exception.content)['error']['message']
                print ('Request %s returned API error : %s : %s ' %
                     (request_id, exception.resp.status, message))
            else:
                print response

    @app.route("/test")
    def test():
        a_id = 'xxx'
        b_id = 'xxx'
        c_id = 'xxx'
        i = datetime.now()
        yesterday = date.today()
        start = yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        end = i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        """Init and return the Google Analytics service"""
        CREDS = 'credentials/google.json'
        scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
        # Retrieve existing credendials
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(CREDS, scopes)
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credentials.authorize(http)

        # Build the Analytics Service Object with the authorized http object
        session = build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)

        batch = BatchHttpRequest(callback=test_callback)

        a_session = ga_service_test(session, a_id, yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        b_session = ga_service_test(session, b_id, yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        c_session = ga_service_test(session, c_id, yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

        for request in [a_session, b_session, c_session]:
            batch.add(request)

        return batch.execute(http=httplib2.Http())

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        DispatcherMiddleware(app)
```

Comment: may I recommend the official Google Python client library https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/ it may save you some gray hair at very least its on GitHub you could pick apart their code.